# how to copy .so file to jniLibs folder after installing the app

Tags: android, java-native-interface, shared-libraries

I am using .so file in my android studio project.It has 40 mb size and when building apk it makes the apk size large.

I have a solution :

don't include so file in project , and instead, zip it and after installing the app,download it , unzip it and coping it to jniLibs folder and using it...

in a nutshell, I want to download it after installing the app and using it.
is it possible and how?

the main part of my question is about **how to copy the so file that is downloaded to jniLibs and use it**.

Comment: So its better to create a split apk's for different architecture instead of removing so file

Comment: but still if you want to do this then try reading https://developer.android.com/google/play/expansion-files

Comment: @Madhur thanks, but i am uploading the app to another store and it is not google play and it can't accepts different architectures of app. and also it doesn't have the the google play feature that is described in that link. I want to download the so file from my special link and use it.

Comment: so probably you there is no way to do so the reason why google provides expansion file is it has a limit of 100 mb per apk, so if you are using other store you dont worry about size limit upload full apk anyways your apk wont work without this so.

Comment: _"is it possible?"_ Yes. _"and how?"_ You've basically already described one feasible approach in your question. Note that these files would be zipped in the APK as well, since an APK is just a ZIP file with a specific structure.

Comment: @Madhur actually the reason why I am concerned is because the user's internet speed is slow and large apk about 50 mb is annoying them. this lib is not so essential so I want to let them choose whether have it or not.

Comment: @Michael ok , thanks.. could you please explain more or do you have any useful link?